# MongoDB collection for user profile

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What would be the best approach to develop the user profil section (is there any defferences?):
Option 1-Put the user details in the profile part of the users collection
ex:
**Collections**
users {

- _id: ...
- usename
- email
- profile[

   
   - name
   - bio 
   - age 
   - location 
   - etc
  ]

}
or use
Option 2-create a separate collection to keep all the user profile informations

ex:
**Collections**
users {

- _id: ...
- usename
- email
- isActiveProfile: true

}
userActiveProfile {

- _id
- userId
- name
- bio
- age
- location
- etc

}

Comment: Without knowing your use cases, scalability needs for the data sets and much, much more, this question is impossible to answer. You might want to read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you'll want to attach it to the user collection since there is a 1:1 relationship between user and their profile, meaning: a user will only ever have 1 profile. The only reason to do it the second way is if you're planning on each user having multiple profiles.